# Укоротить код и объединить JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется следующее:

```js
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip1").click(function(){
            $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip2").click(function(){
            $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
 и тд
```

```css
    #panel,#flip,#panel1,#flip1,#panel2,#flip2,#panel3,#flip3,#panel4,#flip4,#panel5,#flip5,#panel6,#flip6,#panel7,#flip7,#panel8,#flip8,#panel9,#flip9,#panel10,#flip10,#panel11,#flip11,#panel12,#flip12,#panel13,#flip13,#panel14,#flip14,#panel15,#flip15,#panel16,#flip16,#panel17,#flip17  {
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:solid 1px #fff;
    padding:5px;
    }
    
    #panel,#panel1,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4,#panel5,#panel6,#panel7,#panel8,#panel9,#panel10,#panel11,#panel12,#panel13,#panel14,#panel15,#panel16,#panel17 {
    display:none;
    padding:50px;
    }
```

```html
     <div id="flip1"> Название чего-то там(развернуть) </div>
        <div id="panel1"> тут текст </div>
    <div id="flip2"> Название чего-то там(развернуть) </div>
        <div id="panel2"> тут текст </div> и тд
```

Как можно объеденить код JS?

Comment: див панель идет сразу за дивом флип?

Comment: лучше перейти на классы, чем использовать подобный подход и наткнуться на 1000 элементов на странице

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если порядок появления в документе *flip* и *panel* совпадает, то можно так:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(".panel").eq($(".flip").index(this)).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  /* text-align: right; // иначе в сниппете текст перекрывается кнопкой */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">Название 1(развернуть)</div>
<div class="panel">Текст 1</div>
<div class="panel">Текст 2</div>
<div class="flip">Название 2(развернуть)</div>
<div class="flip">Название 3(развернуть)</div>
<div class="panel">Текст 3</div>
```

В данном варианте *flip* и *panel* могут идти в любом порядке (не обязательно panel сразу после flip). Например:

```
flip(1), flip(2), flip(3), panel(1), panel(2), panel(3)
```

или

```
panel(1), flip(1), panel(2), panel(3), flip(2), flip(3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще один вариант, только если структура HTML не будет изменяться:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[id*=flip]").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="flip1">Название чего-то там(развернуть)</div>
<div id="panel1">тут текст</div>
<div id="flip2">Название чего-то там(развернуть)</div>
<div id="panel2">тут текст</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то так:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $("#flip1").click(function(){
            $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $("#flip2").click(function(){
            $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $("#flip1").click(function(){
            $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $("#flip2").click(function(){
            $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

**Еще короче:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var index = i ? i : '';
            $("#flip" + index).click(function(){
                $("#panel" + index).slideToggle("slow");
            });
        }
    });
```

**Еще**

`HTML` превратите в такой вид

```
<div class="flip"> Название чего-то там(развернуть) </div>
<div class="panel"> тут текст </div>
```

`JS` в такой

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```